# FatalError('Invalid head of packet (0x%s)' % hexify(b)) while uploading on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, compilation-errors

I have this error while uploading my code to ESP8266 despite the fact that the code runs without errors. I have the git version of installation for the board.

**ERROR:**

```
File"C:/../../AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 1889, in slip_reader
raise FatalError('Invalid head of packet (0x%s)' % hexify(b))
esptool.FatalError: Invalid head of packet (0x46)
esptool.FatalError: Invalid head of packet (0x46)
```

Any help with this? Thanks.

Comment: is the esp8266 in flashing mode?

Comment: How do I know If its in flashing mode?

Comment: io 0 must be pulled down at boot to start in flashing mode. how did you wire the esp8266 module? how is it connected to PC?

Comment: why do you say that the code runs without errors? ... how can the code run if you are unable to load it into the ESP8266?

Comment: I press the "verify" button and is running without errors.
My esp8266 module is connected via usb cable.

I didn't understand what you are saying about "io 0 must be pulled down..."